# Building the project without launching eclipse product

Tags: eclipse, build, project

I need help on building the project without launching eclipse product. I'm building a eclipse plugin for couple of mainframes. The project that i'm creating is not of Java project and it has has different project nature ( we have customized it for the mainframe ). now i need to build this project without launching the eclipse product. I went through the help and tutorials of Buckminster, but in vain. did not get anything in concrete to implement ( I admit that i did not understand anything there).

Appreciate anyone guiding me how to accomplish building the project.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a "headless" Eclipse builds. That is, you have access to Eclipse facilities without running the UI. [See this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-PDE-Automation/automation.html)